# Why didn't people taking up the Ice Bucket Challenge die?

Tags: neuroscience

I recently came across [Vagal Inhibition](http://healthdrip.com/vagal-inhibition/). That article says,

> (5) Sudden immersion of body in cold water.

can cause *vagal inhibition* and ultimately death.

Recalling the [Ice Bucket Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Bucket_Challenge). Going by what the above article says, shouldn't many of the participants have had a vagal inhibition ?

Comment: For one thing the ice bucket challenge is not immersion, you also might want to look at the mammalian dive reflex.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, any treatment can cause death. [Drinking water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_intoxication) can be lethal and [oxygen is highly toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity) and a strong oxidizer.

To quantify toxicity we usually use [Median Lethal Dose (LD50) metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose). That is a dose at which half (50%) of test group is going to die.

To answer "Why didn't people taking up the Ice Bucket Challenge die?":

**Dose that people used was not high enough to cause any significant increase in mortality**. Maybe some people did die, but it was just masked by other news ([to some degree](https://www.google.com/search?q=ice%20bucket%20challenge%20mortality))